# CalendarView setMinDate() and setMaxDate(); Issue

Tags: android, datetime, calendar

I am working with [**CalendarView**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView) Where I have to set minimum date and maximum date.

I have **startDateTimeMillis** and **endDateTimiMillis.**
I am going to set minimum and maximum date as below.

```
startDateTimeMillis =1517164200000 //(29-01-2018)
endDateTimiMillis =1517682600000 //(04-02-2018)
calendarView.setMinDate(startDateMillis);
calendarView.setMaxDate(endDateMillis);
```

Now strange issue occurs with **calenderView.**

- Minimum date set correct but maxDate goes to **28-02-2018**.

**STRANGE..!!**

you guys can check it by given code.

Answer (score 6):

Working around whole day, I got solution. but didn't get why this strange thing happens??

I just swap lines and it worked like charm.

old:

```
calendarView.setMinDate(startDateMillis);
calendarView.setMaxDate(endDateMillis);
```

resolved:

```
calendarView.setMaxDate(endDateMillis);
calendarView.setMinDate(startDateMillis);
```

Wonderfully it works fine...

Hope this will be helpful to other also.

Comment: Thank you for this. It was a very strange bug indeed.

Comment: Yes. indeed. :-)

Comment: You are my hero. Saved me lots of hours of work